# HQL expression for map querying

Tags: java, hql

I have the following class mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn
    @Column
    @JoinTable
    private Map<String,String> properties;

}
```

I need to query in HQL searching for elements such that:

- `!properties.containsKey(SOME_KEY)` (or)
- `properties.get(SOME_KEY)` in (SOME_VALUES)

The query should return all results for which the key is not defined or is contained in the values I provide.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean `SOME_KEY` in `SOME_VALUES` instead of `properties.get(SOME_KEY)` in `(SOME_VALUES)` ?

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote. Should I rephrase for better understanding? Either the entity **does not** feature any property with given key, or **the only** property with the given key lives in the array of `SOME_VALUES`

Comment: What you wrote makes sense. Just confirming to make sure.